# How to restrict user to rename a running executable (exe) file

Tags: winapi, windows-7, exe, file-rename, file-security

In Win7 I observed that I can rename a running process file name, I searched about it and came across that this feature is introduced so that application itself can update the binary.

I have a windows service and I do not want to allow user to rename it when it is in running state. Please could anyone tell me how can I secure running process file from renaming?

Thanks,

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann - My service logs some important activity and should be in running state all the time that is why I want to suppress this feature/wish.

Comment: @arx don't worry I am not developing any malicious application. Regarding service related questions I am developing a break logging application for a firm that maintains user availability on machine and on behalf of availability we generate payroll, But, some users are renaming my service, that's why I asked this question. Regarding my BITCoin question it was related to my freelance work where user wanted to build gcc code for windows.

Comment: When your service is running, can't you just open the executable yourself for reading, with no shared access?

Comment: @SKAR Fair enough.  icabod's solution works, but the more conventional way to handle this kind of thing is to install software into the Program Files directory where users don't have permissions to mess with it.

Comment: Thanks @icabod , your solution suits best to my scenario.

Comment: Yes it is an another solution @arx, but I also have to cover users having admin privileges.